# Maximum of the length of a curve and its curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, curves

I'm trying to solve this problem but I can't find any way to do it. Some hints or helps will be very useful and I'll be very thankful. The problem says:

Let $\alpha : (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular parametrized plane curve. Assume there exists $t_0\in (a,b)$ such that the distance from the origin to the trace of $\alpha$, $\Vert\alpha(t)\Vert$, attach a maximum at $t_0$. Show that the curvature $\kappa$ of $\alpha$ at $t_0$ satisfies $$ |\kappa (t_0)|\geq \dfrac{1}{\Vert\alpha(t_0)\Vert}.$$

This problem is in the book Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, Manfredo Do Carmo.

Comment: You can find the solution here: (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1645849/304978)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Assume arclength parametrization and apply your single-variable calculus knowledge to $f(s)=|\alpha(s)|^2$.

Comment: I have considered that before, but after differentiate and equal to $0$ the result at $t_0$ what can I say?

Comment: More calculus knowledge:  You know more about $t_0$ than just that it's a critical point.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see your point... Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Could you please give me the solution or another hint? I need to solve this problem

Comment: That's the point: *You* need to solve it. What did the problem tell you happens at $t_0$? How did you use that? You know more than $f’=0$ at that point.